# How to configure Time Manager with Raster Data?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have a number of separate raster layers, which I would like to view with the Time Manager plug-in. I choose each layer, let TimeManager know the date and dateformat from the filename as you can see here:

[image]

But as you can see from the screenshot as well, the date on the time slider only shows 1970-08-21 and nothing really happens -- changing "time frame start" to 2013 does not help either.

I am obviously doing something wrong here ... any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice how the time format in your screenshots reads "SECONDS F...". This means that the values you entered (e.g. 20130117) are interpreted as seconds rather than dates. To avoid this problem, please use the format YYYY-MM-DD when entering dates.

Comment: the satellite images are delivered with the date in their filename YYYYMMDD --- is then there another way to have Timemanager read them automatically? I thought choosing the time format as %Y%m%d as in the screen shot would define it as such?

Comment: to answer my own comment ... I see now that a date format YYYYMMDD is simply not supported ... so that's why my definition %Y%m%d does not work and is interpreted as seconds ...