# Time Manager raster date format error

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am having a problem using the QGIS time manager plugin when adding a raster layer. It tells me that the format of the timestamp field (I converted it to a text column) that I am referencing did not succeed, but it looks like the data is in the correct format. My column is a text type in the table, as mentioned. Is there something that you can see that I may be doing wrong (print screens below)? I was also trying to follow advice for adding the timestamp column with formatting that I found here, but I still receive an error:

https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/159

[image]

[image]

the last character in the next screen is my cursor, not a pipe :)

[image]

[image]

OpenLayers preview of the timestamp column (text type) from GeoServer:

[image: OpenLayers Preview from GeoServer]

QGIS 2.14.20-Essen

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

QGIS raster layers have no attributes. I'm not quite sure where the GeoServer updatetime is coming into play but I doubt that TimeManager can access it. Instead, you have to manually specify the timestamps as shown in [How to configure Time Manager with Raster Data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184471/how-to-configure-time-manager-with-raster-data)

Comment: My apologies, and thank you for the response. I am new to geoserver, so I appreciate your patience.. I just read this post: https://anitagraser.com/2015/08/10/using-timemanager-for-wms-t-layers/ and I got a little further in both my progress and my understanding. However, now I am getting repeated authentication challenges in an "Enter Credentials" window. It looks like it is attempting to make the rest call now with the date range entered, but how do I set the authentication? It says "GeoServer Realm at localhost", Username: "admin?TIME=2018-01-08 00" and password prompt in the pop-up window

Comment: I reread the post that I referenced, and I added a new server (ie WMS connection) by doing Add Layer -> Connect -> and here I entered the credentials for the user, but still I get the credentials challenge each time the time manager attempts to call the rest api. The geoserver I am referencing is local and I can turn on/off authentication without effecting anyone else. Can I relax or remove the authentication for the WMS/WMTS service somehow? I reviewed the "Security" section of the GeoServer admin page, but I am not sure what to turn off to disable authentication for the rest calls. Thanks

Comment: Ok I removed the ?TIME=2018-01-08 portion from the user id that was popping up in the dialog, and then it retained the credentials for the subsequent calls. Thanks again and sorry for any confusion